# Unable to create a new android project in Eclipse JavaEE IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I just installed Android SDK plugin for Eclipse in my Juno JavaEE IDE for Web developer (downloaded few weeks ago). Now, when I try to create a new Android Application project, strange errors appears:

- either a message like "A package name cannot start or end with a dot", but my package name neither starts nor ends with a dot
- or a message like "Enter an application name", but I have provided a name

It seems that when an error is present (e.g., when the wizard is started, no default name is present so the second message appears), correcting it does not clear the error message.

Further, after having closed and re-opened the new project wizard (with some Eclipse manual restarts in the middle), now the "Compile with" field is empty and there is no mean to fill it in.

My Eclipse version is Juno Service Release 1, build id: 20120920-0800

Answer (score 4):

Sorry having wasted your time, simply I forgot to install Android API.
I thought they came with the download of the Android SDK.

Having installed Android API, the "Compile with" field can be populated and the strange errors disappears